# downloading Blob files with a link or a button

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I found this piece of PHP code to download Blob files, but it starts downloading automatically after I load the page. Can someone show me how to make that happen with a button click?

```
$query = "SELECT * " .
          "FROM tbl_uploads WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die('Error, query failed');
list($id, $file, $type, $size,$content) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//echo $id . $file . $type . $size;
//echo 'sampath';
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $content;
```

Comment: Please show us "this piece of PHP code" or any code for that matter so we can help you.

Comment: sorry forgot to paste it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following HTML code to download Blob files with a link:

```
<a href = "download.php"> Download</a>
```

Put the code that you've posted above into **download.php** and this should work.